# SUM of duplicate rows query in sql

Tags: sql, sum, duplicates

I want to build a SQL query which will eliminate duplicate values of ref and manager and calculate the amount of hours for each duplicate

Sample data :

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

I tried to do a sql query but it does not succeed. can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure how "Bil" turns into "Bill", but this is a very simple `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff op is even naming the resulting column with the right function....just needs the `GROUP BY`

Comment: `select ref, manager, sum(hours) from your_table group by ref, manager`

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer